# How to release a IplImage created by imdecode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

I don't know how to free memory in the case of an IplImage created like this:

```
Mat matrixJpeg = cv::imdecode(Mat(jpegBuffer), 1);
IplImage fIplImageHeader = matrixJpeg;
```

This won't work:

```
cvReleaseImage(&fIplImageHeader);
```

I will get error:

```
1   IntelliSense: argument of type "IplImage *" is incompatible with parameter of type "IplImage **"    c:\users\richard\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\server\server\server.cpp 59  19  Server
```

This won't work either:

```
cvReleaseImage(fIplImageHeader);
```

I will get error:

```
1   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "IplImage" to "IplImage **" exists   c:\users\richard\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\server\server\server.cpp 59  19  Server
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: May you are mixing old and new interface? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/memory_management.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not dealing with pointers. The memory is on the stack you have nothing to release until the end of scope.

The [`operator IplImage() const`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat) from `Mat` specifies that no data is copied.